# Repeating sequences in a single matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot

Say I have 2 vectors:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
b = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1];
```

I want to plot these vectors against each other, a being X, and b being Y.

However, while I want the plotted point to be in the correct location, I want the actual values shown on the X axis to be a function of the values in a, where the result of the function is repeated over a given period AND I want these values to be sequential along the axis.

For example, say the function for the value to show on the X axis is `mod(a - 1, 3) + 1`.  I would like for the X axis to read something like 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 as in 
[image: example graph]

I have a feeling that some combination of `subplot` and `axes` may be required, but I'm not seeing anything obvious in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this via the axes properties `xtick` and `xticklabel`.

```
set(gca, 'xtick', a, 'xticklabel', mod(a,3)+1);
```

This won't give you the ticks you've described, but `mod(a-1,3)+1` will. I'm not sure if you wanted the function you gave or the picture you showed, though.

Comment: Thanks! (and good catch on my ever-recurring off-by-one error; fixed it)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the XtickLabels, like so,

```
>> set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'1','2','3'})
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case I needed a programmatic approach.